# Liferay Configuration Action Class - Spring dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

In Liferay, the Configuration Action class is defined in liferay-portlet.xml
The problem is, if I use any spring dependency injection, it's not working.

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>search</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <configuration-action-class>com.mypack.MyConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>search-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
    <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
</portlet>
```

Action Class implementation

```
public class MyConfigurationAction extends DefaultConfigurationAction {

    private @Value("${test.property1}") String property1;
    private @Value("${test.property2}") String property2;
}
```

How do I inject these properties into this Action class, without using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and hard coding spring.xml file in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to save preferences in portlet development[in liferay],

1. Through liferay specific way, which uses liferay-portlet.xml entry . cant be managed with spring.
2. JSR-286[portal agnostic], portlet EDIT mode.

While developing portlet with Spring MVC framework, its advisable to use portlet EDIT mode.

In Spring MVC portlet framework, you can map portlet requests by portlet mode.

For Example: Create controller class as below which will map to EDIT mode requests.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("EDIT")
public class PreferencesController
```

with two methods, one method with annotation @RenderMapping, responsible for view and other method with annotation @ActionMapping/@RequestMapping responsible for storing preferences.

Hope this would help.

Comment: I enabled EDIT mode in portlet.xml and done as you said. But this class is not getting invoked at all. The request is always sending in VIEW mode only when I click on Configuration. If I click on Preferences, it's altogether generating Exception and no call to Controller

Comment: No, you have to click on Preferences, and what exception its generating

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
portlet.xml

<supports>
.....
<portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
</supports>
```

**Controller class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "EDIT")
 public class XYZ{
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "Configuration" is NOT "Edit" mode. If you enable Edit mode (as suggested by others), you'll get "Preferences" button in your portlet menu. It is a Liferay feature that you can override as per your requirement.

I have Not tried this myself but you can try to use `@Autowired` to AutoWire your MyConfigurationAction class (and possibly use `@Required` annotation if needed?). Don't forget to put `<context:annotation-config/>` in your applicationContext.xml file, if not already done.

Comment: first thing the Configuration class [bean] is not created by Spring, thus Spring can never inject any dependencies even if you mark with any annotation and put extra conditions

Comment: I guess you answered it for yourself. I also checked in the Liferay source if I can find a way to achieve this, but the class is instantiated by EditConfigurationAction class. So it won't work this way.